# Problems structuring .NET Core application in subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In **.NET 4.6** I am used to have my projects organized in projects/folders like this:

```
MyApp
  \MyApp.Core
  \MyApp.Data
  \MyApp.Service
  \MyApp.Web
```

I'm trying to create a simple application using **.NET Core 1.1 and Visual Studio Code**.

First I created a new folder for my application and executed the command:

```
dotnet new -t web
```

A new application was created, and when I run it from the command line or from the debugger in VS Code everything works fine.

However, all the source code is in the root. To organize my code better, I created a folder called `src`, and a folder under src called `MyApp.Web`, like this:

```
MyApp
  \src
    \MyApp.Web
```

I also updated `launch.json` and `tasks.json` to reflect my changes:

Snippet from **launch.json**

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\MyApp.Web\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.1\\MyApp.Web.dll",
```

Snippet from **tasks.json**

```
"args": [
   "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\MyApp.Web\\project.json"
]
```

When I run it from the command line it works fine, however when I run it from VS Code debugger it builds fine but I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

I'm guessing it's looking for a folder called Views in the root directory, however it should look for this folder under `/src/MyApp.Web`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing bit.

Snippet from **launch.json**

Change: `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"`

To: `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/MyApp.Web"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` solved the same issue for me.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
```

Comment: This line was not missing on mine after generating a web application using  `dotnet new -t web`